# Is it possible to convert a List to a JCR Value?

Tags: java, reflection, nodes, jcr

So I am using reflection to create a new instance of a List. I then want to set that list to a Node. The problem is Nodes only take primitives, Strings, Value, and Value[]. I get a ClassCastException when I try to do this:

```
 Value[] valueArray = (Value[])Array.newInstance(elementType,size);
```

I would like to do :

```
node.setProperty(name,valueArray);
```

Has anyone come across a way to do this properly? Or places that would lead me in the right direction? Is this even possible?
Thanks for looking.

Comment: I didn't get it. Why don't you use just `Value[] valueArray = new Value[size];`?

Comment: Ideally I would love to be able to put actual real values/objects in the nodes. However, if someone cannot see a better solution than this I am certainly not opposed.

Comment: What do you mean by real values? Value is interface (http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.jcr/jcr/1.0/javax/jcr/Value.java). Real instances of it you typically make with help of ValueFactory (http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.jcr/jcr/1.0/javax/jcr/ValueFactory.java) which is also interface. It's implemented in every case. Here is an example: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.exoplatform.jcr/exo.jcr.component.core/1.16.2-GA/org/exoplatform/services/jcr/impl/core/value/ValueFactoryImpl.java#ValueFactoryImpl

Comment: What is JCR implementation you're working with? Or your task is to make such implementation?

Comment: I'm trying to create my own implementation using JCR values and nodes.I would like the objects of list in the property to not be null when the property is set. However I may have to find some other work around for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So why don't you just have your own implementation of Value, for instance like this:

```
class MyValue implements Value {
    private Object value;
    private int type;

    public MyValue(Object value) throws RepositoryException {
        if (value == null)
            throw new RepositoryException("Value can not be null");
        this.value = value;
        if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            type = PropertyType.BOOLEAN;
        } else if (value instanceof Calendar) {
            type = PropertyType.DATE;
        } else if (value instanceof Double) {
            type = PropertyType.DOUBLE;
        } else if (value instanceof Long) {
            type = PropertyType.LONG;
        } else if (value instanceof String) {
            type = PropertyType.STRING;
        } else {
            throw new RepositoryException("Wrong type: " + value.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Binary getBinary() throws RepositoryException {
        throw new RepositoryException("Wrong type: " + value.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getBoolean() throws ValueFormatException,
            RepositoryException {
        if (type == PropertyType.BOOLEAN)
            return (Boolean)value;
        throw new RepositoryException("Wrong type: " + value.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    public Calendar getDate() throws ValueFormatException, RepositoryException {
        if (type == PropertyType.DATE)
            return (Calendar)value;
        throw new RepositoryException("Wrong type: " + value.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal getDecimal() throws ValueFormatException,
            RepositoryException {
        if (type == PropertyType.DECIMAL)
            return (BigDecimal)value;
        throw new RepositoryException("Wrong type: " + value.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    public double getDouble() throws ValueFormatException, RepositoryException {
        if (type == PropertyType.DOUBLE)
            return (Double)value;
        throw new RepositoryException("Wrong type: " + value.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    public long getLong() throws ValueFormatException, RepositoryException {
        if (type == PropertyType.LONG)
            return (Long)value;
        throw new RepositoryException("Wrong type: " + value.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getStream() throws RepositoryException {
        throw new RepositoryException("Wrong type: " + value.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    public String getString() throws ValueFormatException,
            IllegalStateException, RepositoryException {
        if (type == PropertyType.STRING)
            return (String)value;
        throw new RepositoryException("Wrong type: " + value.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value.getClass().getSimpleName() + "(" + value + ")";
    }
}
```

Then you array code wouble be like:

```
    Value[] valueArray = new Value[size];
    valueArray[0] = new MyValue(123L);
    valueArray[1] = new MyValue(123.45);
    valueArray[2] = new MyValue("12345");
```